# Spark Storage Best Practice

Tags: amazon-s3, cassandra, apache-spark, hdfs

I am planning to deploy a Spark cluster. Spark supports many storage schema such as HDFS, S3, HBase, Cassandra, Hive, etc.

Since I am not migrating from Hadoop to Spark, I have no existing 'big data' storage and still trying to figure out which one would be the best choice.

What is the best way to store data to optimize Spark to the fullest?
My use case is tracking user behavior data and use spark as ETL to create data warehouse and other data products.

One thing that came to my mind is having HDFS storage in each of worker node, just like what Hadoop storage schema usually is.

Comment: Strictly, HDFS, S3, HBase, Cassandra, Hive are not storage schema. For example, Hive supports different storage format such as RCFile, Parquet, ORCFile. And all the format I listed above are formats based on HDFS.

Comment: Based on different kind of applications you would love to run on spark, you  may prefer different kinds of storage format, please be specific of your workload in your question description.

Comment: In general, I would suggest S3, but it really depends on your dataset